# Is there any way to resolve this image loading exception caught in firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm uploading a profile picture of the user which is stored in the firebase storage. Then in my app I'm retrieving the image from the firebase storage using url of the image, but the image is not loaded and it throws an exception.

```
I/flutter (32361): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32361): The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (32361): Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 400,
I/flutter (32361): https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/writers-den.appspot.com/o?name=profilepics%2F1442.jpg&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uoz7-Wm8gikpX5O8Tc1B9vDWFUXkVpqBMxoXvyHrBzk1FHGqeA47uWJbrOlCl56bWmX3rabPq5Qxs5hACVobwDXX1X7SA&upload_protocol=resumable
I/flutter (32361):
I/flutter (32361): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (32361): #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:496:7)
I/flutter (32361): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (32361): #1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:475:14)
I/flutter (32361): #2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:105)
I/flutter (32361): #3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:157:22)
I/flutter (32361): #4      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:82)
I/flutter (32361): #5      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:38:29)
I/flutter (32361): #6      ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:283:30)
I/flutter (32361): #7      DecorationImagePainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart:239:55)
I/flutter (32361): #8      _BoxDecorationPainter._paintBackgroundImage (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:414:19)
I/flutter (32361): #9      _BoxDecorationPainter.paint (package:flutter/src/painting/box_decoration.dart:432:5)
I/flutter (32361): #10     RenderDecoratedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1968:16)
I/flutter (32361): #11     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #12     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #14     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #15     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #16     RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:70:15)
I/flutter (32361): #17     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #18     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #19     RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:70:15)
I/flutter (32361): #20     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #21     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #22     _RenderFlex&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2273:15)
I/flutter (32361): #23     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:7)
I/flutter (32361): #24     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #25     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #26     _RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2273:15)
I/flutter (32361): #27     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:361:5)
I/flutter (32361): #28     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #29     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #31     _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:504:11)
I/flutter (32361): #32     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #33     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #34     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #35     PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:370:12)
I/flutter (32361): #36     RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1717:17)
I/flutter (32361): #37     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #38     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #40     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #41     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #43     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #44     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:128:11)
I/flutter (32361): #45     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:96:5)
I/flutter (32361): #46     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:190:7)
I/flutter (32361): #47     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:171:7)
I/flutter (32361): #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #49     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #50     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #51     RenderAnimatedOpacity.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:910:17)
I/flutter (32361): #52     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #53     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #55     RenderFractionalTranslation.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2448:13)
I/flutter (32361): #56     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #57     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #59     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #60     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:128:11)
I/flutter (32361): #61     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:96:5)
I/flutter (32361): #62     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:190:7)
I/flutter (32361): #63     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:171:7)
I/flutter (32361): #64     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #65     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #66     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #67     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #68     RenderOffstage.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3045:11)
I/flutter (32361): #69     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #70     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #71     _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2273:15)
I/flutter (32361): #72     RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:594:5)
I/flutter (32361): #73     RenderStack.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:602:7)
I/flutter (32361): #74     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #75     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #76     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #77     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #78     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #79     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #80     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #81     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #82     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #83     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #84     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #85     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #86     RenderPointerListener.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2629:11)
I/flutter (32361): #87     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #88     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #89     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #90     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #91     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #92     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #93     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #94     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #95     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #96     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #97     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:128:11)
I/flutter (32361): #98     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:96:5)
I/flutter (32361): #99     PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:190:7)
I/flutter (32361): #100    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:171:7)
I/flutter (32361): #101    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #102    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #103    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #104    RenderAnimatedOpacity.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:910:17)
I/flutter (32361): #105    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #106    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #107    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #108    RenderFractionalTranslation.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2448:13)
I/flutter (32361): #109    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #110    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #111    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #112    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #113    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:128:11)
I/flutter (32361): #114    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:96:5)
I/flutter (32361): #115    PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:190:7)
I/flutter (32361): #116    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:171:7)
I/flutter (32361): #117    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #118    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #119    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #120    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #121    RenderOffstage.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3045:11)
I/flutter (32361): #122    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #123    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #124    _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2273:15)
I/flutter (32361): #125    RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:594:5)
I/flutter (32361): #126    RenderStack.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:602:7)
I/flutter (32361): #127    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #128    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #129    __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #130    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #131    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #132    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #133    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #134    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #135    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #136    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #137    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #138    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #139    RenderPointerListener.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2629:11)
I/flutter (32361): #140    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #141    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #142    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #143    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #144    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #145    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #146    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #147    PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:173:13)
I/flutter (32361): #148    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:123:15)
I/flutter (32361): #149    RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2092:7)
I/flutter (32361): #150    PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:128:11)
I/flutter (32361): #151    PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:96:5)
I/flutter (32361): #152    PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:853:29)
I/flutter (32361): #153    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:331:19)
I/flutter (32361): #154    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (32361): #155    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
I/flutter (32361): #156    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
I/flutter (32361): #157    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
I/flutter (32361): #158    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:840:5)
I/flutter (32361): #162    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
I/flutter (32361): #163    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
I/flutter (32361): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (32361):
I/flutter (32361): Image provider:
I/flutter (32361): NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/writers-den.appspot.com/o?name=profilepics%2F1442.jpg&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uoz7-Wm8gikpX5O8Tc1B9vDWFUXkVpqBMxoXvyHrBzk1FHGqeA47uWJbrOlCl56bWmX3rabPq5Qxs5hACVobwDXX1X7SA&upload_protocol=resumable",
I/flutter (32361): scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (32361): Image key:
I/flutter (32361): NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/writers-den.appspot.com/o?name=profilepics%2F1442.jpg&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uoz7-Wm8gikpX5O8Tc1B9vDWFUXkVpqBMxoXvyHrBzk1FHGqeA47uWJbrOlCl56bWmX3rabPq5Qxs5hACVobwDXX1X7SA&upload_protocol=resumable",
I/flutter (32361): scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (32361): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Code for uploading the image:

```
    uploadImage() {
var randomno = Random(25);
final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('profilepics/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(newDp);

task.onComplete.then((value) {
  userManagement
      .updateProfilePic(value.uploadSessionUri.toString())
      .then((val) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HmPg()));
  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
  });
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
    }
```

In my firebase storage I can see the image which I uploaded, even the url of the image works fine.
I updated the security rules to public but still same exception is thrown.
Allowed `storage` permission to my app, updated `AndroidManifest` still no success.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213980)? It provides a workaround, since exceptions probably can't be caught using NetworkImage.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to fetch here is the upload URL for the file upload. I suggest getting the download URL from the upload task to access the image.

```dart
UploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(newDp);

task.then((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
  debugPrint('Download URL: ${taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()}');
});
```

You can then use this download URL to access the file from Firebase Storage.